# Magento 1.7.0.2 Upgrade (From 1.6.2)

Tags: php, sql, magento

I have recently caught wind of the inherent Zend problem that Magento is built upon.  I took that initiative to upgrade my sites from 1.6.2 to the newest 1.7.0.2 to resolve that problem.  All my sites upgraded beautifully except 1.  All the files are up to date on the server now, but when I try to access my site and it runs the upgrades, I get the below report saved in my reports folder without access to my site.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:216:"Error in file: "/home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/data/sales_setup/data-upgrade-1.6.0.4-1.6.0.5.php" - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main.base_tax_refunded' in 'field list'";i:1;s:883:"#0 /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(407): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('data-upgrade', '1.6.0.4', '1.6.0.7')
#2 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(286): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeData('1.6.0.4', '1.6.0.7')
#3 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(269): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyDataUpdates()
#4 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(351): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()
#5 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /home/xxxxxx/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Or if I try to upgraded via the downloader I get:

```
Exception during cache and session cleaning: Error in file: "/home/xxxxxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/data/sales_setup/data-upgrade-1.6.0.4-1.6.0.5.php" - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main.base_tax_refunded' in 'field list'
```

This is a problem I have yet to run into with my many moons of administering magento.  Lookin into the code for that php, everything seems standard, and matches the other sites i have installed the upgrade on.

Anyone run into such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ben,  I've upgraded four Magento stores now to 1.7.0.2 from 1.5.1.0 and 1.6.2.0. Not exactly the same problem, but two had some form of missing table (one was a captcha_log, the other was sales_order_tax_item. Once I created the 'missing' table each installation was fine. Not sure why they were or went missing. Might you just add the missing column or replace the table with a correct version? base_tax_refunded is in the sales_flat_order table.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved.

Turns out my index.php file was set to 666.  Ran a chmod to change it to 755 and all is well again!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem but the field was in my main orders table and changing permissions of files had no effect, so eventually after looking at the files that was given the errors more closely (i.e. data-upgrade-1.6.0.4-1.6.0.5.php) I added following columns to the following tables and at last I can get back into my admin panel.

Columns Added: base_tax_refunded,discount_refunded,base_discount_refunded

to Tables: sale_flat_creditmemo,sales_flat_creditmemo_item,sales_flat_order_item

Surely this kind of thing would be done automatically by the upgrade scripts? unless I missed some step...